# Does DisplayPort support scaling natively?

Tags: displayport

In the DisplayPort Wikipedia page, in advantages section it is stated that "Can drive display panels directly, eliminating scaling and control circuits and allowing for cheaper and slimmer displays".

In the DisplayPort 1.2 specification, it is stated in external connection objectives that " Support external display configurations that do not include scaling, a discrete display controller, or on screen display (OSD) functions, enabling low cost, digital monitors. "

DisplayPort 1.2 specification - https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://glenwing.github.io/docs/DP-1.2.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjkq-_xgrDmAhVsxTgGHaCjCB0QFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw1P2cs_sDfKQF4AX6NoqNMa

Does this mean DisplayPort will upscale or downscale according to display panel connected without a scaling unit in between ?[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A DisplayPort cable simply transmits electrical signals without changing them.

Objective 3) just says that a display that is not capable of scaling is DisplayPort compatible. In other words, the DisplayPort specification does *not* require that all displays must support scaling.

If you have a display that does not support scaling, and if your source is not able to generate images in the correct resolution, then the system will not work. Allowing this failure mode was seen as an acceptable tradeoff to avoid higher costs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It cleared up the doubt I had